# Which Rspec convention is more up to date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Which Rspec convention is more up to date and should be used in new projects ?

```
subject { [] }
it { should == [] }
```

or

```
subject { [] }
it { expect(subject).to eq([]) }
```

I haven't found way of composing shorter version using subject implicitly with `expect` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `expect` (your second example) is the more up to date version. Rspec is moving away from methods being added onto existing objects (such as `should`) because they can occasionally cause odd behavior.

Comment: I know this, but overhead in comparison to `should` version is remarkable.

Comment: The problem is should doesn't always work, such as on proxy objects. Quickly googling it I found [this article](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) which explains it quite well

Comment: There is a shorthand for the expect syntax: `it { is_expectected.to eq([]) }`.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in https://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/

> In the future, we plan to change the defaults so that only expect is available unless you explicitly enable should. We may do this as soon as RSpec 3.0, but we want to give users plenty of time to get acquianted [sic] with it.

I quote from this site:

> The underlying problem is RSpec’s should syntax: for should to work properly, it must be defined on every object in the system… but RSpec does not own every object in the system and cannot ensure that it always works consistently. As we’ve seen, it doesn’t work as RSpec expects on proxy objects. Note that this isn’t just a problem with RSpec; it’s a problem with minitest/spec’s must_xxx syntax as well.

Personally, I use a mix of both still, as all "shoulda" matchers use the old syntax anyway, and are so easy to use...